# 403 forbidden error if querystring url param is a valid url string

Tags: http

I have this query string

`article.php?title=sometitle&source=somesource&url=http://someurl.com`

url param is urlencoded
But I get the 403 error

If i change url param to something else other then a url string e.g. `&url=test` then it works fine.

Any idea why is it happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you hosting this on some 3rd party hosting provider? Refer this discussion http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=244525 - it might help in your case. Also, try `base64_encode()` the URL parameter and see if that helps!

Comment: The `url` parameter is likely only accept an address relative to the server. i.e.: without protocol and host name.